# Is it possible to use variables for Display in COBOL?

Tags: cobol

For example if we want to display `"HELLO world "` at position `10, 10` in screen we use

```
DISPLAY (10 10 ) "HELLO world " .
```

now instead of `10, 10` is it possible to use variables?

```
DISPLAY ( x y ) " HELLO WORLD " .
```

Here `x` and `y` are variables.

Is it possible to use like this or what is the replacement code?

Comment: Try it and let us know.  What version of Cobol are you using?

Comment: Yaa i tried ...and found that                                                      DISPLAY "HELLO WORLD " LINE X POSITION Y .                                   IT WORKS.. :)

Comment: What's the PICTURE of X and Y?

Comment: 9 ( a single digit integer )

Comment: How did you fit 10 in a single digit integer?

Comment: Then I'm surprised 10 10 works :-) What COBOL? Can you show the full data-definitions?

Answer (score 3):

OpenCOBOL (and some other compilers) allow `DISPLAY stuff AT xxyy END-DISPLAY` but in that case xxyy would need to be a literal.

See Gary Cutler's very complete (and open FDL licensed) OpenCOBOL Programmer's Guide at http://opencobol.add1tocobol.com/OpenCOBOL%20Programmers%20Guide.pdf and look to section 6.14.4